# regex replace matchEvaluator using string Array

Tags: c#, regex

I need to highlight search terms in a block of text.

My initial thought was looping though the search terms. But is there an easier way?

Here is what I'm thinking using a loop...

```
public string HighlightText(string inputText)
{
    string[] sessionPhrases = (string[])Session["KeywordPhrase"];
    string description = inputText;

    foreach (string field in sessionPhrases)
    {
        Regex expression = new Regex(field, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        description = expression.Replace(description, 
                                         new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeywords));
    }
    return description;
}

public string ReplaceKeywords(Match m)
{
    return "<span style='color:red;'>" + m.Value + "</span>";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by easier? That code looks pretty easy to me. Do you mean more efficient, shorter, more useful.... ?

Comment: yes, more efficient. is there a regex replace function that handles array replacement already?

Comment: It is very important to use Regex.Escape on your field. Otherwise you could get "regex injection", granted, not as bad as sql injection but not good nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the loop with something like:

```
string[] phrases = ...
var re = String.Join("|", phrases.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)).ToArray());
text = Regex.Replace(re, text, new MatchEvaluator(SomeFunction), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You might want to add `@"\b(" +re + @")\b";` around that so that you only highlight exact matches.

Comment: Also note that when you use this construct, you no longer need a MatchEvaluator.

Comment: @jhsowter, text is read only "once". While in the original solution it's read "once" for every word/phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Qtax's answer:

```
phrases = ...

// Use Regex.Escape to prevent ., (, * and other special characters to break the search
string re = String.Join("|", phrases.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)).ToArray());

// Use \b (expression) \b to ensure you're only matching whole words, not partial words
re = @"\b(?:" +re + @")\b"

// use a simple replacement pattern instead of a MatchEvaluator
string replacement = "<span style='color:red;'>$0</span>";
text = Regex.Replace(re, text, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Not that if you're already replacing data inside HTML, it might not be a good idea to use Regex to replace just anything in the content, you might end up getting:

```
<<span style='color:red;'>script</span>>
```

if someone is searching for the term script.

To prevent that from happening, [you could use the HTML Agility Pack in combination with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926301/detect-email-in-text-using-regex/8960753#8960753).

[You might also want to check out this post which deals with a very similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230035/complex-regular-expression-for-two-consecutive-words-or-a-single-word-c-sharp/9284446#9284446).

Comment: You seem to be assuming the "keywords" always start and end with word characters.  I'd get a ruling on that before suggesting the use of `\b`.